# How to hide listview when clicked, and reroute to another page?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, menu, listviewitem

I'm currently creating a menu with a ListView and ListViewItems. In the menu, I want to go back from one page to a predefined page. The ListviewItem, which were clicked, should disappear when it takes me back to the predefined page. However, I'm stuck at how the flow between the views is handled and how to hide the ListView when it is clicked.

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="GoBackMenu" Foreground="#FF5C99D6" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="ListViewMenu_ClashPressed" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" Margin="0 0 0 290" Visibility="visible" >
                <ListViewItem x:Name="Swift_goBackView" Height="80">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Backburger" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="10"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Back to overview" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ></EventSetter> 
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle></ListView>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you add the XAML that surrounds this `ListView` and the code that is fired when the `ListViewItem` is clicked? It would help me understand the context of your code better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the clicked item like this in your event handler:

```
private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)sender;
    GoBackMenu.Items.Remove(lvi);
}
```

How the "the flow between the views is handled" depends on your current navigation implementation which you haven't described.